# How to create a new LaTeX command that behaves something like \verb?

Tags: latex

I have been using LaTeX from sometime now, but have never actually gotten my hands dirty declaring a new command, as I try to avoid that.

However, I need to add monospace text often in my document and I use `\verb` for it which is fine, except that the verb font size is bigger than the normal text font.  So I need to change the font size and undo done like `\small{}\verb#My monospace code#\normalsize{}`.  This is not very convenient and mistake-prone.

Is there a better way to do this? Can I define a new command for this? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining new commands that act like the verbatim commands is actually quite difficult.  The LaTeX `verbatim` package contains some stuff that will help.

If you are using the `times` package, the Computer Modern verbatim font does not go well with the PostScript times fonts.  For a more suitable verbatim (typewriter) font try

```
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{aett}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not use the `\texttt{}` command to get monospaced text?

I'm not sure why the `\verb` command is giving you text that's larger than normal (for me, `\verb` is exactly the same size as regular text, and `\texttt{}` as well). However, if you really want to make a new command to get you smaller monospaced text, you might try defining a command in your header as follows:

```
\newcommand{\smalltt}[1]{{\small\texttt{#1}}}
```

Where the `[1]` indicates that the command takes one argument (the text to make small and monospaced.) Then of course you'd use it as `\smalltt{my smaller monospaced text.}`.

Answer (score 1):

As Noah says, the size should not be different between `\verb` text and normal output. It would be a good idea to post a small, complete example of the form:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Text and \verb|verbatim % text|.
\end{document}
```

If you want to pick up text to process verbatim with formatting, things are a bit complicated by the need to watch catcodes. I'd look at the fancyvrb or listings packages for this.

Answer (score 1):

Put the following line in a .sty file included by your document:
\renewcommand{\verbatim@font}{\ttfamily\small}

Answer (score -1):

Let me give some examples of new command:

```
\newcommand{\zope}{Zope}
```

Now whereever I give `\zope` in my Latex text, its replaced by the text specified above. This if I need to make a global change I can make it.

```
\newcommand{\bi}{\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\ei}{\end{itemize}}
```

With the help of the two commands above, now I can write my lists as:

```
\bi
\item 1st item
\item 2nd item 
\item and so on...
\ei
```

This illustrates how some commands can be shortened with the help of newcommand.

Now lets consider a newcommand with a parameter.

```
\newcommand{\filepath}[1]{\verb!#1!}
```

To use this command, I would write something like `\filepath{abc.xml}` which will be replaced by `\verb!abc.xml!` on processing the command.

Another example:

```
\newcommand{\ida}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
```

With help of this `\ida{myVariable}` is replaced with `\textcolor{blue}{myVariable}`

I hope this small tutorial will help serve the purpose.

Comment: Nice examples but, critically, the one with \verb doesn't work.

Comment: Let me amend that by saying that it won't work to escape special characters in the input like \verb is supposed to do.